# Write a apex Trigger which prevents changing the email address on a Contact

Tags: apex

Can someone give source code for the above requirement, I have tried it but it is throwing error

```
trigger Email_Check_On_Contact on Contact (before update) {
  Map<Id,Contact> o = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    o = trigger.oldMap;
    for(Contact newcont: trigger.new)
    {
      
        if(newcont.Email != o.Email && o.Email!=Null )
        {
            newcont.Email.addError('Email cannot be changed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use validation rule instead ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use validation rule instead for this requirement. That would be simpler to use and easier to maintain as well.

Your validation rule will be as simple as below

```
ISCHANGED(Email) AND NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Email)))
```

But if you still want to go with trigger, then below should trigger should suffice your needs

```
trigger Email_Check_On_Contact on Contact (before update) { 
    Contact o;  
    for(Contact newcont: trigger.new) {   
        o = Trigger.oldMap.get(newcont.Id);
        if(newcont.Email != o.Email && o.Email!=NULL ) {
            newcont.Email.addError('Email cannot be changed');         
        }     
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1- for Validation Rule

Comment: why we are using NOT  operator ,(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Email))) this isblank returns true and it  throws error message itself

Comment: That is because, to throw an error only when there was a value earlier and user is trying to update it. If the earlier value is blank, you allow the user to update it. If that's not the case, you can remove the entire condition.